React Mui DatePicker - cs localisation
I'm trying to use DatePicker in Czech language.
I used this code
import * as React from 'react';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import 'dayjs/locale/cs';

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const language = 'cs';
  dayjs.locale(language);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker label="Test picker" />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

The problem is that the months were translated correctly, but the letters indicating the names of the days remained in English. In addition, in the Czech calendar, the day starts on Monday, here it starts on Sunday (see screen).

when I look in the dayjs/locale/cs file, all the translations are fine, but the calendar does not reflect this.
The full example is here: enter link description here
Is there anyone here who can identify the problem?
